# How do I recover ubuntu 12.04 after failed hardware update?

Tags: software-installation

After selecting "install" on "hardware updates are available" on update window of Ubuntu 12.04 (The line that is under 14 release upgrade prompt) a black screen apeared writing some things that i cannot understand. Please note that  I have no idea about software management. How can I return to my previous Ubuntu 12.04 situation?

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! Typically you have to click the details button to get the black screen which provides detail on unpacking, configuring and installing packages being done in the background. Is this the black screen you are speaking of?

Comment: If you accidentally saw a black screen with a ton of incomprehensible gobbledygook *but your system works fine* there is no need at all to go back to your previous situation!  This is normal and happens very seldomly: it only happens when you accidentally click the `details`  button...  **;-)**

Comment: Hi @ElderGeek I think that this is the screen you are describing! But I do nto know how can I reach any (!) button! I cannot see buttons at all!

Comment: Hi @Fabby Can you help to find the DETAILS button?

Comment: I have a series of screens in jpg format that describing what I am seeing but I do not know how to upload them! Any help?

Comment: The only thing I can do is to write something in a raw that starts with: dim@dim-P4i65G:~$_

Comment: No I can't.  I first need to get an update...  But when I do, I'll get back to your question (set as favourite already)

Comment: @Dimitris you can upload images to imgur.com and provide the links here.

Comment: @ElderGeek here the sequence of screens that I can see... <iframe class="imgur-album" width="100%" height="550" frameborder="0" src="//imgur.com/a/xbBNm/embed?background=f2f2f2&text=1a1a1a&link=4e76c9"></iframe>

Comment: @ElderGeek I think I did something wrong in the previous message. Here is the sequence of screens http://imgur.com/9hXfIHA, http://imgur.com/FtA12B0, http://imgur.com/fAxxWMu, http://imgur.com/GY0eJ7n, http://imgur.com/T9Xx3p2, http://imgur.com/yGO9708

Comment: @Fabby Yes you are right! I saw the screens that you have posted below. But when all this "spectacle" ended I did not know what to do! You can see the sequence of screens that I am seeing after the "upgrade" on the message to ElderGeek above. The update I did was hardware update, possibly a graphics card update.

Comment: Choose "Run in low graphics just for one session".  Then login normally, press [Ctrl][Alt][T] and type `sudo lshw -class video` and provide a screen-hot of the output...

Comment: Your current problem is system running in low graphics mode: see this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Stop worrying!

Apparently when you did a software update you saw this:

[image: Software update]

and then you accidentally pressed the <kbd>Details</kbd> button, so you saw something like this:

[image]

**and that is absolutely no problem!**  Don't worry, as long as you don't press the details button, you will not see any gobbledegook any more!

This is just what happens in the background when your computer does updates and some people (like me) actually *like* to see this happen when they do software updates!  **;-)**

Comment: yes may be you are right! This how it was started, but when all this "spectacle" ends I cannot do anything (or precisely I do not know what to do!) Here is the sequence of screens I am seeing:  imgur.com/9hXfIHA, imgur.com/FtA12B0, imgur.com/fAxxWMu, imgur.com/GY0eJ7n, imgur.com/T9Xx3p2, imgur.com/yGO9708